# Wordpress opens new window everiwhere

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a wordpress page and every link I have it opens into a new tab. This happened when I change the wordpress from localhost to a remote server.

What can be the problem?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide more info? Such as linking as the page, for example, so we can check the problem?

Comment: http://vps136896.ovh.net/edujm17/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check the HTML page source, you can see that every link in your page has the `target="_blank"` attribute, which means that every time you click on them, the browser will open a new tab.

If you didn't put the `target="_blank"` manually (hence i suggest you to check your theme .php files) something may inject them when the page is loaded. Thus there might be some possibilities:

1. A plugin you (or the theme) maybe installed is changing all links to open in a new tab
2. That theme has a particular option which enable this behaviour and filter pages and rewrites the links.

Without any more information, it's a little hard to answer your question...